# Converting Firebase database data from string into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, firebase, for-loop

I am trying to build a chat bot using Xenioo platform and their "List" function is returning compile error. Bypassing that I manged to get the data from Firebase into a JavaScript variable:

```
        { documents:[{
  "documents": [
    {
      "name": "projects/*******/databases/(default)/documents/Assets/QWEWQXLUyOl8vQXypHo7",
      "fields": {
        "Lawyer Phone": {
          "stringValue": "6"
        },
        "Sale Type": {
          "stringValue": "7"
        },
        "Area": {
          "stringValue": "2"
        },
        "Address": {
          "stringValue": "1"
        },
        "Lawyer Name": {
          "stringValue": "5"
        },
        "District": {
          "stringValue": "4"
        },
        "Asset Type": {
          "stringValue": "3"
        },
        "Additional": {
          "stringValue": "0"
        }
      },
      "createTime": "2019-06-06T17:42:30.592904Z",
      "updateTime": "2019-06-08T15:52:36.649013Z"
    },
    {
      "name": "projects/*******/databases/(default)/documents/Assets/fzdbqZFet4GskHqVTGaT",
      "fields": {
        "Additional": {
          "stringValue": "a"
        },
        "Lawyer Phone": {
          "stringValue": "g"
        },
        "Sale Type": {
          "stringValue": "h"
        },
        "Area": {
          "stringValue": "c"
        },
        "Address": {
          "stringValue": "b"
        },
        "Lawyer Name": {
          "stringValue": "f"
        },
        "District": {
          "stringValue": "e"
        },
        "Asset Type": {
          "stringValue": "d"
        }
      },
      "createTime": "2019-06-08T15:50:38.053127Z",
      "updateTime": "2019-06-08T15:52:27.389321Z"
    }
  ]
}
]}
```

I want to be able to work with this data as normal array or some thing that I can simply loop and filter data by user requirements for example:

```
var data = "";

for( var i=0; i < result.length; i++ ){
        data += result[ i ].Additional + "\n";
}
```

The language I am using is JavaScript, I am Noby so I would really appreciate help.

Comment: Maybe https://medium.com/chrisburgin/javascript-converting-an-object-to-an-array-94b030a1604c? But you should probably take the time to learn about JavaScript objects, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object

Answer (score 0):

I believe the first thing to do is to transform the variable into an object instance.

```
var value = conversation.GetVariableValue( "my_firebase_data" );
var instance = JSON.parse( value )
```

after that, you can pretty much do whatever you want with the variable, so for example:

```
for( var i=0; i < instance.documents.length; i++ )
   [any operation]
```

I also think Xenioo is supporting direct variable parsing in your chatbot, like "Hello {{data[0].first_name}}" etc..